# update index after a delete operation

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a Customer Table that has a CustIndex column.  From the UI a User can delete a customer that was for example at Index 3.  What I need to do then determine if there was a Customer with an Index at 4 and renumber it to be 3, (so basically keep the sequence).

At the minute I just have some code like below:

```
    private void UpdateCustomerIndexes(IList<CustomerDTO> customers)
    {
        var customerIndexes = customers.Select(c => new { c.customerId, c.customerIndex });

        //unitIndexes.Select(u => u.)
    }
```

I am keeping wanting to keep the CustomerId so if I need to update the DB I can say update customer set index = 3 where customerid = 4 for example.

So if I had 5 customer on the UI and I delete Customer at Index 5

If I set a breakpoint on customerIndexes, the data is:

```
{ CustomerId = 33, CustomerIndex = 1 },
{ CustomerId = 34, CustomerIndex = 2 },
{ CustomerId = 35, CustomerIndex = 3 },
{ CustomerId = 36, CustomerIndex = 4 }
```

So, in this case, the CustomerIndex is in sequence so there is nothing to do.  However, lets say now I deleted CustomerIndex 2 on the UI.  The data would now look like:

```
{ CustomerId = 33, CustomerIndex = 1 },
{ CustomerId = 35, CustomerIndex = 3 },
{ CustomerId = 36, CustomerIndex = 4 }
```

Now the Customer Index is out of sequence and I need to renumber CustomerIndex 3 to 2 and CustomerIndex 4 to 3 and then save this to the DB so I can say make the update statements setting the Index to the new value for that CustomerId.

I know my CustomerIndex will never go above 50 so would it be an idea to use something like:

```
var list = new List<int>(new[] { customerIndexes.Select(c => c.customerIndex) });
var result = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Except(list);
```

However, I think this will only tell me if a number in sequence is missing - I am missing how to save which index needs to be updated for which customerid or do nothing in the case when they are in sequence

Comment: Before how to do it you need to decide whether you should do it or not. And that depends on the use of CustomerIndex column. Resetting column value for entire table can give you some other issues. What if table has thousands of rows, it will take longer to complete the delete operation with resetting column values. That can lead to data inconsistencies and data corruption.

Comment: You really never want to store that type of information in a table, things like that can exist sparsely - i.e. with gaps - as the order is preserved an ordinal value can be calculated dynamically when its needed.  Consider what happens if multiple users manipulate the data concurrently.

Comment: @Alex K...multiple users wont be able to do this due to the login process.  Each agent will only have control of a certain ramge of customer which only they can manipulate.  That isn't my design but that is how it is done for this app.  So unfortunately I need to maintain it in the DB though I understand your valid point

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya - yeah I understand what you are saying but unfortunately I am stuck with this data model so I have to do it

Comment: @mjwills - ill give that a go - might be a better idea and more straightforward than I was thinking.  Note I won't have to cascade this to other tables - the CustomerIndex is just a stand alone column on one table to hold the number of that customer in the sequence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After** you delete the record with `CustomerIndex` of 2, run the following SQL:

```
UPDATE TableName SET CustomerIndex = CustomerIndex - 1 WHERE CustomerIndex > 2
```

This will ensure the CustomerIndex of all 'greater' records are reduced by 1 to compensate.

*Similarly, if a customer deletes CustomerIndex of 5, change both references to 2 above to 5.*

Comment: what check would I need to run to make determine if there is an out of sequence record - lets say I have 5 records and delete the record where CustomerIndex was 5, that will set CustomerIndex 3 to 2 and 4 to 3 when they should not have been updated?

Comment: will I have to declare a temp variable in my delete stored proc - set the CustomerIndex of the record to be deleted to temp variable before I do the delete and then do the update.  I take it would also need to do a check that there is more than 1 CustomerRecord before doing the update - i.e. if I had CustomerIndex of 1 and delete it then there would be nothing to update

Comment: If you want to do a stored proc, then the first line of your stored proc would be the DELETE of the row you want to delete, and the second would be the above SQL. There is no need to do a check before the UPDATE - if there are no records to update the UPDATE will still execute fine (it just won't do anything).

Comment: I'll still need to hold that CustomerIndex of the one that is being deleted though so I can run the update statement?

Comment: Yes you will. Whatever value (which presumably you provided via a parameter to the stored proc) you passed to your DELETE statement is the same one you will pass to the UPDATE statement.